# This is the strangest browser to HTML/CSS disconnect I have ever seen

Tags: css, html, google-chrome

So, I am currently rebuilding my portfolio and I have built sites using HTML5 before and have never seen this. I am wondering if I used the tags properly and if that is what is causing the disconnect.

[Here's a live link](http://lisareisman.com/tests/portfolio13/about.html) so you can try it yourselves and the code will follow.

If you look at this page in Firefox, everything is here it should be (btw, this only applies to the interior pages, not the index) BUT look at it in Safari or Chrome. Then, inspect element and you will notice that the tag 'section' and everything inside that tag is not being seen by the browser in the css.

Now, what makes me think it is something outside that tag that I am missing is when I changed it to a 'div and gave is a class of section, still had same result.

I have also tried the Modernzr and the 'section' tag didn't even show up on the list. And, it validates 100%.

**Note:** I removed a lot of the extraneous content leaving the outline intact. For example, the 'ul' tags all have more than one line item. I was concerned about non-essential code getting in the way of a clean view.

**Edited code:** Added class to section to try and snag it in the browser, and added the CSS for the `section` tag.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Lisa Reisman, portfolio, web design, Atlanta, Georgia, print, photography, responsive web design, CSS3, HTML5, javascript, transitions, ">
<meta name="description" content="The portfolio of freelance designer Lisa Reisman, interactive and print, photography and planning in Altanta, Georgia.">
<title>Lisa Reisman Portfolio - About Lisa</title>

<link href="css/keyframes.css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/basic.css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<!--jquery-->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(onclick) {
        $("a#about").addClass("slideDwn");
        $("a#inter").addClass("slideUp");
        $("a#print").addClass("slideUp");
        $("a#photo").addClass("slideUp");
    }

</script>

<!--modernizer-->
<!-- <script src="js/modernizr.custom.71520.js"></script> -->

<!--google analytics-->
</head>
<body id="about_pg">
<main id="wrap">
    <aside>
        <div id="sidehead"><a href="index.html" title="Lisa Reisman Portfolio Web Site"><span class="l">L</span> <span class="r">R</span></a></div>
        <div id="sidenav">
            <ul id="subnav">
                <li><a id="about" class="slide" href="about.html" title="About Lisa Reisman">A</a><span class="word">bout</span></li>
                <li><a id="inter" class="slide" href="interactive.html" title="Lisa Reisman Interactive Projects">I</a></li>
                <li><a id="print" class="slide" href="print.html" title="Lisa Reisman Print Work">P</a></li>
                <li><a id="photo" class="slide" href="photo.html" title="Lisa Reisman Photography">Ph</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--end side nav-->
    </aside><!--end aside-->

    <div id="innersocial">
        <ul id="contact">
            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/lisarosereis" title="Lisa Reisman Facebook" rel="external"><img src="i/lisareisman-facebook.png" alt="Lisa Reisman Facebook" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="www.linkedin.com/pub/lisa-reisman/9/22a/912/" title="Lisa Reisman LinkedIN" rel="external"><img src="i/lisareisman-linkedin.png" alt="Lisa Reisman Facebook" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://twitter.com/LisaRose_webD" title="Lisa Reisman Twitter" rel="external"><img src="i/lisareisman-twitter.png" alt="Lisa Reisman Facebook" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Lisa Reisman MySpace"><img src="i/lisareisman-myspace.png" alt="Lisa Reisman Facebook" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="mailto:lisa.reisman@lisareisman.com?subject=Saw%20Your%20Web%20Site" title="Lisa Reisman Email"><img src="i/lisareisman-email.png" alt="Lisa Reisman Email" /></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!--end inner social div-->

    <section class="section" id="about-nav">
        <ul>
            <li class="btn"><a href="#openTech" title="Lisa Reisman Techincal Knowledge">Technical</a></li>
            <li class="btn"><a href="#openIndus" title="Lisa Reisman Industries Experience">Industries</a></li>
            <li class="btn"><a href="i/ReismanResume13.pdf" title="Lisa reisman Resume 2013" rel="external">Resume</a></li>
        </ul>
    </section><!--end section nav-->

    <div id="openTech" class="modalDialog">
        <div>
            <a href="#close" title="close" class="close">X</a>
            <a href="i/ReismanResume13.pdf" title="Lisa Reisman Resume 2013"><img src="i/lisareisman-download_resume.png" alt="Lisa Reisman Resume" /></a>
            <h2>Technical Knowledge</h2>
                <h3>Advanced</h3>
                    <h4>Apps</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Illustrator • </li>
                    </ul>
                    <h4>Developer Tools</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>DreamWeaver • </li>
                    </ul>
                    <h4>On-The-Job Skills</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Organized • </li>
                    </ul>
                    <h4>General Advanced Abilities</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Responsive Web Design • </li>
                    </ul>
                <h3>Intermediate</h3>
                    <h4>Apps &amp; Frameworks</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>After Effects • </li>
                    </ul>
                    <h4>Developer Tools</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>PHP/MySQL • </li>
                    </ul>
                <h3>Working on Expanding Knowledge</h3>
                    <h4>Apps, Frameworks &amp; Miscellaneous</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Bootstrap • </li>
                    </ul>
                <h3>Platforms</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Apple • </li>
                    </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!--end tech modal-->
    <div id="openIndus" class="modalDialog">
        <div>
            <a href="#close" title="close" class="close">X</a>
            <h2>Industry Experience</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li>Medical • </li>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!--end industries modal-->
</main><!--end wrap-->
</body>
</html>


/*=== PAGE CONTENT ===*/
section.section {
width: 680px;
float:left;
margin: -285px 62px 0px 205px;
opacity: 1; 
}
 section.section .fade {
opacity: .0;
animation: fade .75s ease;
-webkit-animation: fade .75s ease;
-o-animation: fade .75s ease;
-moz-webkit-animation: fade .75s ease;
}
 section.section .switch {
-webkit-transition: margin-top .75s ease .5s;
-moz-transition: margin-top .75s ease .5s;
-o-transition: margin-top .75s ease .5s;
transition: margin-top .75s ease .5s;
}
 section.section li:first-child.btn {
padding-right: 16px;
}
 section.section li.btn {
height: 66px;
width: 300px;
font-size: 3em;
line-height: 2.0;
padding: 0px 16px 0 7px;
}
 section.section li a {
/* padding: 0 7px; */   
-moz-border-radius: 7px;
-webkit-border-radius: 7px;
border-radius: 7px;
border: thin solid #000000;
}
 section.section li a img {
}
```

Comment: Wrong site, one should post working code here, will tag this to move it to SO.

Comment: @LisaRose: There are JavaScript lint programs that will check code for syntax (and other) errors.

Answer (score 2):

At the very least you are missing a closing brace in your jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(onclick) {
    $("a#about").addClass("slideDwn");
    $("a#inter").addClass("slideUp");
    $("a#print").addClass("slideUp");
    $("a#photo").addClass("slideUp");
}); // You were missing );
```

Comment: Thanks for that which explains some other issues!! l;o)

Answer (score 0):

Use `float:left;` for the small circles without `width` or `height`. It will adjust to the size of the text.
Put some `padding` as you need it. 
Your code can be shorter without `jquery` (just plain `javascript` and `CSS`).

Comment: @benka Thanks. I'm more used to math.stack exchange where we use the LaTeX tricks to write 'tt' style.